# problem with iOS 4.2 when user press the list view item to go to UIwebview page and the navigation button disappears on the second visit

Tags: iphone, xcode

My app is a Navigation based application.  The main menu contains the list view items.  if I clicks one of them, it goes to next view which in this case take me to UIwebview embedded web site.  Everything is looking great.  I can view the content of web page, the navigation control back button which takes to the main menu if I press it.  However, I'm having issue when I try to go back to main menu if i visit that subview the second time.  It loads the content of UIwebview web page, but the navigation button is gone and won't let me go back to main menu.  This problem only appears on latest iOS 4.2 version.  Otherwise it works great on 3.1 to 4.1.  I would appreciate any hints or inputs.
Note this seems not working for subview using UIWebview embedded web content.  I don't have any issue with other subviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the code ? Did you try this: `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;` in viewDidLoad method where you are adding UIWebView to your view..

Comment: [super viewDidLoad];
 NSString *urlAddress = nil;
 urlAddress=@"http://www.yahoo.com";

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [[self mymoWV] loadRequest:requestObject];

Comment: Don't see anything that triggers hiding back button !! Anyway can you override using self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO; in view did load after [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: I tried self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO.  but it didn't help.  navigation button appears on 1 visit, then go back and visit second time, button is gone

Comment: can you add self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO to viewWillAppear instead...

Comment: still not working MacDev.  I scanned thru app delegate and couldn't find any codes suspiciously

Comment: What was causing button disappear is that I had placed [self setTitle:@""] in viewWillAppear; in root view controller class which controls the main menu page.  However, the button name displays on the title bar of the main page when i go back from subview.  This can be managed.  Thanks for your inputs